# Trying to use angular-recorder, getting controller not found

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use angular-recorder from https://github.com/logbon72/angular-recorder

```
  Controller 'ngAudioRecorder', 
required by directive 'ngAudioRecorderAnalyzer', can't be found!
```

I have done `bower-install` and added the file to the dependencies.
I am getting the above error when I try to use `<ng-audio-recorder-analyzer></ng-audio-recorder-analyzer>`

### Update

As Y.Puzyrenko states, need to enclose a `<ng-audio-recorder-analyzer>` inside a `<ng-audio-recorder>` for `recorder controller` object to be available.

Code that works:

```
<ng-audio-recorder id='audioInput' audio-model="recorder.audioModel">
    <!-- Start controls, exposed via recorder-->
        Current microphone input:
        <ng-audio-recorder-analyzer  ng-model="a.audioModel"></ng-audio-recorder-analyzer>
        <button ng-click="recorder.startRecord()" type="button" ng-disabled="recorder.status.isRecording" class="btn btn-default">
            Start Record
        </button>
        <button ng-click="recorder.stopRecord()" type="button" ng-disabled="recorder.status.isRecording === false" class="btn btn-default">
            Stop Record
        </button>
        <button ng-click="recorder.playbackRecording()" type="button"
         ng-disabled="recorder.status.isRecording || !recorder.audioModel" class="btn btn-default"> Playback
        </button>
    <!-- End controls-->
</ng-audio-recorder>
```

Comment: can you post up your script orders and the surrounding html for the tag in question? (up to the containing controller or ng-app?)

Comment: @Sk93 hi, sorry for the late response. It seems I needed to enclose the wave tag in a parent ng-audio-recorder tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs 'cause you did'nt specify `ng-audio-recorder` directive on your element, or it's parent.
E.g. `<ng-audio-recorder><ng-audio-recorder-analyzer></ng-audio-recorder-analyzer></ng-audio-recorder>`

[Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq)